# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS Tutorial

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm searching for a documentation / tutorial that explain the ROS basis and also the working way "for newbies" in robotics. The tutorial of ROS is available from website and i would like to know if something more is existing (less technic, more logic)

Regards

Philippe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9639/ros-tutorial/) by [Philippe](https://answers.ros.org/users/381/philippe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-04-05**:
What were your expectations for the ROS tutorials? Could you give an example?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-20**:
@Philippe what exactly are you looking for ? ROS tutorials will give you an idea as to how ROS functions, 'robotics for newbie' may ask for a different approach !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you find the ROS tutorial too difficult? I found it easy enough to understand and I don't think there is anything simpler out there. If you post specific questions here then people can answer them.

---

Originally posted by [froody](https://answers.ros.org/users/369/froody/) with karma: 46 on 2011-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-20**:
@froody ROS can be difficult if one is not from Computer Science/IT background ! :-)